# Is how can I enable my wifi router to accept Bitcoin for adhoc/ anonymous usage?

Tags: security, network, altcoin, merchants, merchant-services

I want to find a WiFi solution where I can sell my internet service with anyone who needs to use it... ideally paying in an altcoin or Bitcoin.

Are there any router modifications, or infrastructures that support a wallet service?  (e.g. the user pays at the captive portal) and then has time or bandwith limited access to the internet?

I found [this list of router firmware](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-choose-the-best-firmware-to-supercharge-your-wi-1694982764?utm_campaign=socialflow_lifehacker_facebook&utm_source=lifehacker_facebook&utm_medium=socialflow) that may support such modding, but not sure which one is best (and most secure) for the job.

Lacking that, perhaps I can leverage RADIUS authentication.

Comment: This should be able to be done via a RADIUS server...

Comment: if RADIUS is a requirement perhaps you could edit the question as that was not clear in the initial question it appears you are more interested in firmware

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called [wifiportal21](https://github.com/aantonop/wifiportal21) that uses the [21 Bitcoin computer](https://21.co/buy/) in conjunction with an OpenWRT router running the wifidog captive portal software.  This is still in beta at this time, but seems to suit your application.

It is also worth noting that OpenWRT does have the ability to create a separate network that cannot pass traffic to the main network, and works with RADIUS authentication.

Answer (score 0):

So... it happens I did a research project on this during my exchange semester.

https://github.com/renlord/biternet

TLDR; The software charges based on usage on an interval. Invoices are sent periodically to the browser which triggers payment, if there aren't any sufficient bitcoins, after several warnings, the entry node will eventually revoke access. Technologies used include IpTables, OLSRd and Node.

Although it wasn't done on OpenWRT, I hope this is useful.